# Specifying a build action (e.g. install) in Xcode GUI

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to specify a build action, for example `install` using Xcode GUI?

I can do

```
xcodebuild install
```

from the command line but can't find a key ACTION in the build settings in the GUI menu, or any relevant menu items.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured that if I set both **Deployment Location**(DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION) and **Deployment Postprocessing**(DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING), then the build process installs the product and also copies public/private headers. Setting **DeploymentPostprocessing** is required no matter what the actual postprocessing is.

Also, both **Installation Directory**(INSTALL_PATH) and **Public/Private Headers Folder Path**(PUBLIC/PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH) are assumed to be under **Installation Build Products Location**(DST_ROOT), so the product and headers will be located there.

One thing that bothers me is that **Installation Directory** should start with "`/` " in order to correctly appended to DST_ROOT. For example, if DST_ROOT is `/myDistributionRoot/` and INSTALL_PATH is `lib/`, then the destination directory becomes `/myDistributionRootlib`, not `/myDistributionRoot/lib`.