# How do I "make install" via xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile

I have an xcode project that builds a library from C/C++ sources for OSX.  Is there a way to get xcode to install the library and its header files into /usr/local/lib?

I have the following settings under Target > Build Settings:

- Deployment

  - Deployment Location = Yes
  - Deployment Postprocessing = Yes
  - Installation Build Products Location = /tmp/projname.dst
  - Installation Directory = /usr/local/lib
  - Skip Install = No

When I do Product > Build, it puts the resulting .a and adds the public headers into an include/ subfolder in the /tmp/projname.dst/ folder.  But I come from the land of Makefiles and I'd like to have the equivalent of "make install" here (I expect it to ask me for permissions when it tries to put things into /usr/local/include/ and /usr/local/lib/)

Comment: It seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136172/specifying-a-build-action-e-g-install-in-xcode-gui

Answer (score 5):

It looks like "xcodebuild install" is how you do this.