# Copying Framework from derived data to /Library/Frameworks (Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, frameworks, copy, installation

This seems like it should be a very basic question. I've been programming for 30 years in over a dozen languages, but somehow the Apple build and deployment system always leaves me scratching my head.

I want to arrange it so that when I do a build, my framework output files are copied from the deriveddata location to /Library/Frameworks. I have tried several approaches to this, creating a copy step in the build phases, but nothing seems to work right. I get complaints about "This target might contain its own product" if I specify a destination of "Shared Frameworks". If I specify an absolute path I get permissions problems. If I say "only copy files when installing", then I can't figure out how to get Xcode to "install". I would go out and buy a book on Xcode and Apple deployment, but the versions change so quickly I'm afraid it would be out of date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should add some code that shows your current work in progress, the boilerplate text is unnecessary for SO questions :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136172/specifying-a-build-action-e-g-install-in-xcode-gui This answer did it.