# Xcode won't install my command line tool

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7

How do I get Xcode to install a command line tool I've written? I'm using Xcode 7 with os x10.11 . Using Xcode's Project Setups, I've written a "Hello World" command line tool. In Build Settings, under Deployment I have /usr/local/bin for "Installation Directory" and "skip installation" is NO. The project has default Targets and Schemes. The program compiles and runs fine.

I cannot get Xcode to copy the binary into the /usr/local/bin directory.

I've tried "Build" "Run" and "Archive" schemes.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: I can get it to copy the file if I put the file in the "Copy Files" part of build settings and uncheck "Copy only when installing"

Comment: This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136172/specifying-a-build-action-e-g-install-in-xcode-gui

Comment: I found this post: This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136172/specifying-a-build-action-e-g-install-in-xcode-gui It had the answer to the problem.